# Why C++ not know TIMESTAMP_STRUCT type?

Tags: c++

I use Visual Studio 2005

When I compile, I get this error:

> Error    1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'mDropEndTime'
>
> Error    2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

```
struct MB_SYN_DROPITEM_UPDATE : MSGBUF
{
    long                    mCid;           // Index
    unsigned long           mItemIdx;       // idx
    TIMESTAMP_STRUCT        mDropEndTime;   // This is error line
};
```

Why doesn't C++ know `TIMESTAMP_STRUCT`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TIMESTAMP_STRUCT` is something defined in sqlext.h

You must add

```
#include <sqlext.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because TIMESTAMP_STRUCT is not part of the C++ standard.